# Why whatsapp click to chat link on wordpress redirect to 'send to' on whatsapp instead of the person's chat?

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp

simple task I supposed but maybe I missed something. I have added a 'click to chat' whatsapp link to my whatsapp icon on a wordpress website, but it redirects the user to a 'send to...' page instead of the individual's phone number's chat page. Did I missed anything here?

[Whatsapp Icon on website linking to chat](https://snipboard.io/H0LekK.jpg), once clicked the whatsapp icon, it redirects to '[send to...](https://snipboard.io/Rileha.jpg)' page on whatsapp.

I have tried all these links below but they all redirect to the same 'send to...' on whatsapp:

- https://wa.me/0123456789
- Wa.me/0123456789
- whatsapp://send?phone=0123456789
- https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0123456789
- https://wa.link/xxxxx, where x is the unique code

**mobile number is just an example*

**header.php**

```
removed
```

**index.php**

```
removed
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**
Here's the documentation and answer for those who are using Porto theme and encounter the same whatsapp problem. Big thank you to the brilliant @Aneesh for helping.
https://www.portotheme.com/wordpress/porto/documentation/faq/how-to-fix-whatsapp-number-and-clicking-to-take-to-whatsapp-chat-on-header-and-footer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked, the href link starts with: **whatsapp://send?text**
Which asks for SEND TO option on the mobile screen. What you need to do is, remove whatsapp://send?text and just keep it as: **https://wa.me/message/ASDFASDFASDF**

### In short, your current code looks like:

```
<a  rel="nofollow" class="share-whatsapp" style="display:none" href="whatsapp://send?text=https://wa.me/message/ASDFASDFASDF" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" title="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</a>
```

### How it needs to look like

```
<a  rel="nofollow" class="share-whatsapp" style="display:none" href="https://wa.me/message/ASDFASDFASDF" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" title="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</a>
```

Try this, and do let me know if you've any more issues.

Note: For the sake of privacy, I've changed the letters are /message/ to ASDFASDFASDF, please replace it with original link.

Comment: Hi @Aneesh, thank you for your response. Here's the link to the page: https://kadaiku.com/ and the whatsapp icon is only available on mobile view

Comment: Hi @ElizaMatthew I've just edited my answer, please check and try.

Comment: hi @Aneesh, thank you for your answer. However, the whatsapp link that I have set is actually already 'https://wa.me/message/ASDFASDFASDF' instead of the one you inspected on my page. Wordpress somehow changed the link to the format that starts with 'whatsapp://send?text ' . Do you have any idea as to why does the format changes automatically? Here's the screenshot of the link that I have set. https://snipboard.io/7R6vUF.jpg

Comment: I believe you need to make changes in your header.php file. 

Go to appearance> Theme Editor > Header.php > Search for WhatsApp > Remove whatsapp://send?text  from the field.

If you want, I may join you on Anydesk to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Hi @Aneesh, I have added header.php code on my question, and I cant find the 'whatsapp' part for it

Comment: Hi @ElizaMatthew can you check in index.php page? Or add the screenshot of Theme Editor page (the right part)

Comment: Hi @Aneesh, there's no option for 'theme editor' on my wordpress admin dashboard, however there is 'theme options' for my social links.. >>> https://snipboard.io/KgfhH8.jpg 
I accessed the header.php and index.php file through FTP.. I have edited my question above to include the index.php code..

Comment: Simply go to your site cPanel and open the layout.php file under wp-content/themes/porto/inc/functions now when the file opens, scroll down to the page at line number 2141 there you see Anchor tag, and then make changes. Or otherwise, I may join you on Skype or Anydesk.

Comment: Hi @Aneesh, following your guidance, I have managed to fix the link on the top bar. however I have another whatsapp social link on the footer that does not get affected by the update. may I know how do you get this source wp-content/themes/porto/inc/functions and the line number so that I can find the problem as well?

Comment: Hi @Aneesh. I found the documentation for it on https://www.portotheme.com/wordpress/porto/documentation/faq/how-to-fix-whatsapp-number-and-clicking-to-take-to-whatsapp-chat-on-header-and-footer/ and it fixed my problems. You have been a great help for me Aneesh, your solutions helped me a lot, thank you so much!! I will flag and accept your solutions as the answer. Thank you!!

Comment: That's very great. Happy to help.